# Regarding gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on a gridview in ASP.Net. I want a particular row to be highlighted on checkbox check so that if any other user logs in the system the row should appear highlighted to them too.

Comment: Show the code What you have tried so far and mention where you are facing issue.

Comment: Mention what you have done. Provide some examples. Help other help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a flag field in your Database table that you bind with the grid view. If you check one row then pass true value to the flag field. Then while you show the Grid view validate like this,

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IsChecked")) == "True")
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir..please give me the query for flag and it's use

Comment: It is so simple @kritiupadhyay You just need to call a Put method in Ajax while you check a checkbox. Take the ID of that checkbox/row Id then update your table. Check my code bellow,                  $("#myId").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        "url": "yourURL/"+id,
        "type": "Put",
        success: function (d) {
            console.log(d);
        }
    })